# How to rename model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator, rename

I made a mistake early in development, and named one of my models with plural noun (`Users` instead of `User`). Is there an easy way to rename it and corresponding controller (similar to generating it with `script/generate` way)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> update: this script is not supported anymore

A script exists that will do the job for you:

http://github.com/hiroshi/script-refactor

Comment: nice!  not something I'm likely to need often, but good to know it's out there.

Comment: I'm bookmarking that one, because it's a PAIN to undo them. Most of the time I just git revert and regenerate.

Comment: Is it possible to use it with rails 3?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to change all the references to `Users` in all your application manually.

To change the name by itself, it's not very hard : rename the file and add the following migration :

```
class RenameUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        rename_table :users, :user
    end
    def self.down
        rename_table :user, :users
    end
end
```

Comment: Table name should be plural, thus "users" is fine.

Comment: Right ! But in his model, the table is probably not named users so he'll have to rename it

Answer (score 4):

You need to rename your file, your test/spec file and all reference to this model.

You also need to make a migration to rename the table.

Answer (score -1):

no easy way that I know of, http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=32693

i think you've just got to do it manually

don't forgt to rename all your tests too....